# laravel eloquent relation 3 models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, relationship

I have a Laravel 5.4 project where these are some of the models: **Client**, **Owner**, **Employee**, **Bank** (actually it is Bank Account but I have chosen Bank for easy naming conventions in building relationship with foreign keys).

### Now here are some facts:

- each Client can have many Banks (Bank Accounts).
- each Owner can have many Banks (Bank Accounts).
- each Employees can have many Banks (Bank Accounts).
- each Bank (account) can have Only one [either Client or Owner or Employee]

What is the best way to build the tables and the relationship.
I have thought of the following:

### Tables:

- clients: id, bank_id, other fields...
- owners: id, bank_id, other fields...
- employees: id, bank_id, other fields...
- banks: id, client_id, owner_id, employee_id, other fields...

### Model Relationships

- Client hasMany Banks and Bank belogsTo Client [done as instructed by Laravel]
- Owner hasMany Banks and Bank belogsTo Owner
- Employee hasMany Banks and Bank belogsTo Employee

Now when building Bank Blade View Forms (Create/Update)
should I have a drop-menu e.g. **belongs_to** field having Client, Owner, Employee as options - then accordingly, I can filter out One of the three tables to choose id of the ***holder*** of bank account to allocate it.

### Disadvantage:

each Bank will have only active foreign key - at a time - for one of the 3 tables e.g. client_id = 36 and the other two are always 0 in their value e.g. owner_id = 0 & employee_id = 0)

Is this is the best way in building the relationship or there is another better way? Please provide the blade view form for banks if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a great candidate for a [polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations).

Your table structure will look something like:

- clients: id, other fields...
- owners: id, other fields...
- employees: id, other fields...
- banks: id, bankable_id, bankable_type, other fields...

The main differences from your proposed structure is the fact we do not specify the bank in the clients, owners or employees table (since they can have multiple). Instead we specify what type of user the bank belongs to using bankable_id and bankable_type.

Then in each of your three user models; clients, owners and employees, you have the following (it may be best to put this in a trait):

```
public function banks()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Bank', 'bankable');
}
```

In your banks model, you can then have:

```
public function bankable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Which will return the user (a client, owners or employees model) that owns the bank.

Comment: Yes, it is the perfect way to do Polymorphic Relation but did not work as is and returns empty collection because it cannot resolve the Client/Owner/Employee class path.

To sort this out either: 
* Store full path of the models e.g. App\Client in bankable_type field in db  
OR
* Map the relation in Bank model above class declaration:

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
Relation::morphMap([
    'client' => 'App\Client',
    'owner' => 'App\Owner',
    'employee' => 'App\Employee',
]);

* I prefer the second solution as it decouples db from laravel code.

Answer (score 0):

This relation would suit a [Polymorphic Relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations).

You can have your Bank accounts apply to one of the other relations like this

```
class BankAccount extends Model 
{
    public function accountOwner()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Client extends Model
{
    public function bankAccount()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('BankAccount', 'bankAccount');
    }
}
```

Note that I've used the name `BankAccount` because I really recommend using a name that specifically mention what it represents. In the future you or some other developer might get confused about "Bank" actually meaning "Bank Account". And you should also consider what you would do if you decided to add Banks to your model, so each account belongs to a "Bank".

The obvious disadvantage of polymorphic relations is the fact that you cannot have physical foreign keys on the database tables.

Comment: Yes, this is the perfect way to do it as Polymorphic Relation but did not work as is and after investigation I have found the following:
* the relation return empty collection because it can not find the Client/Owner/Employee class path and to sort this out: